# List files with php

Tags: php

I'd like to know how to listing files with php?

What I try to do is it was sailing along this list of files in order that when it chooses one of them (.html) it me appears in the iframe that I have in my (index.php). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
$path    = 'path to the directory';
$files = scandir($path);
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readdir [link to readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Look at this exemple:

```
 if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
   while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
     if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        echo "$entry\n";
     }
   }
  closedir($handle);
 }
```

Comment: Slightly similar but this the only thing that it does is to there show me the files that I have inside the folder does not allow me the navigation for them. Really thank you.